# Is the "speed of time" perception a quale we can share?

Tags: time, physicalism, qualia, perception, neurophilosophy

The perception of time seems to be a [quale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualia) as every other else. Though, the unique thing about it could be that it's actually measurable.

People regulate their drowsiness by objective factors like light. There's a well known experiment conducted by [Michel Suffre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michel_Siffre) on himself in 1972 - when he spent a month with no light and no information about the time, his time perception, along with his sleeping cycles, has twice slowered. This experiment indicates that our perception of time is heavily interwined with our bodily (objective) sensation but as our thoughts, it seems to have the characteristics of a quale.

On the other hand, there were experiments with similar goals that were about to find out wheter [people percieve](http://www.livescience.com/2117-time-slow-emergencies.html) time slower when they're falling from high on a trumpoline but they didn't. Similarly as the studies on [changes](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/mind-guest-blog/why-does-time-fly-as-we-get-older/) of our time perception during our lifetime, this experiment shows us that our time perception might be often a thing of our memory - this would indicate time isn't even a quale at all.

When I watched the movie Arrival, I realized it wouldn't actually be possible to share one's perception of time - just as it's not possible to share our speed of time.

Though - it seems to me that perception of time is unique in its ability to be shared to a certain extent. Could this be the interface of consciousness and the physical word? Aren't we actually sharing our qualia when we consider ideas such that the time used to run slower when we're young?

I think the similar reasoning logic be applied for thoughts - which might be why some philosophers doesn't consider them to be a quale. What does it mean for the philosophy of consciousness to actually have such interface? Is there any similar dimension of sensation on the border of shareable sensations?

Comment: There is a basic problem with this as a goal: The measurable correlate of a quale, e.g. the wavelength of red light, is not the quale itself.  It is both more than the quale -- in that it has material reality, and less the quale, because the experience can be created by false stimulation when it is absent.

Comment: @jobermark Ok but if was for ex. our perception of time change as we're getting older, it wouldn't really mean anything in the physical word (even though it could have been probably fully described by analyzing our neurons). Appropriate metaphore would, I think, be that our vision would slowly shift towards audio sensation in our lifetimes. My point is not that time is the only scientifically explainable quale but the only which qualities we can describe

Comment: We can describe lots of quale to at least the same degree we can note the effects of time.  The blinding fullness of a bright white light, the tenuous halting due to one kind of pain or the feeling of being engulfed by another, etc. etc.  We have remarkably similar bodies, and they respond to stimuli in remarkably similar ways.  We have the experience and it leaves us changed, at least temporarily.  And the changes can be empathically communicated.

Comment: I understand we can communicate things like colorblindness or hearing loss but those seem to be all things we could simulate with virtual reality. The true qualia are what we can't simulate - and therefore you can't say that we all see red in a remarkably similar way (even though I'd argue for that from philosophical reasons). Time perception seems to be "above" those in the sense that you need time perception to percieve them (wow - I just realized that time perception might *be* consiousness).

Comment: @jobermark We don't really have any clue of what might be *physically/neurologically* causing time perception, do we? I think that's what makes it a quale - we shouldn't really be able to communicate it because that's how we could spot a philosophical zombie. Nevertheless, we talk about "living faster" as we get older.

Comment: You can argue for that from the reason that *our explanations and descriptions are very similar*  that we manage to teach the labels of quale to our children without difficulty.  This seems like outright evasion.  You seem to be distorting the natural language of quale to make time seem special.

Comment: You can argue for that from the reason that *our explanations and descriptions are very similar*  that we manage to teach the labels of quale to our children without difficulty.  This seems like outright evasion.  You seem to be distorting the natural language of quale to make time seem special.  That is all I am trying to point out.

Comment: Our guesses as to what causes differential experience of time can be gleaned from what makes the experience of time disappear.  Consider Winograd's version of Heidegger or Csikszentmihalyi's notion of 'flow': When the means we need are 'ready-to-hand' our experience of time is minimized.  As we get older we have more white-matter, which means that we are more prone to assume readiness-to-hand and less prone to breaking out of it into full processing.

Comment: "*Our explanations and descriptions are very similar*" I assume you wanted to oppose the argument that our explanations for the qualia of vision and hearing in the real world are almost identical to the very descriptions of the qualia. But that's not what I wanted to say. I thing we can't really meet in our definitions of qualia.

Comment: By "qualia" I don't mean the  "perception of green" that can be described as the neural signal in a specific area in brain but the very "experience of green" we actually can't describe now. There's no way I can say if you hear sounds like me or wheter it's closer to my colors. Since now, noone could make good enough description in any real language (or any other form of communication).

Comment: All we can describe in human languages is the actual physical form of the quale. When you say something's brighter, it can in my "audio vision" look like you're saying something is sending a bit higher tone. But the bare information on the physical characteristics of things is not what is not what I mean by *qualia*.

Comment: The flaw here would be that we do not experience the passing of time. Nobody has ever experienced this. My go to thinker on time is Hermann Weyl.and he makes this point clearly. Our awareness in always right now, We may, as you say, get a sense of time passing slowly or quickly, but this is a theory imposed on experiential data, not raw experience. In immediate experience there is no past or future. Our perception of time is not a quale since we do not have such a perception. If we did then the common idea that time is metaphysically unreal would be unsustainable.

Comment: It might help to consider the many definitions of time. For instance there is chronological or metronomic time based on seconds, minutes, hours, etc., the *folk* meaning. Aristotle describes time as 'a number of change in respect of the before and after'. McTaggart in *The Unreality of Time* describes A and B theories of time. Finally there is St Augustine *Confessions, Book X* who asks, “What then is time? If no one asks me, I know what it is. If I wish to explain it to him who asks, I do not know.”

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

Time is an illusion, there is no "forward" or "backward" or "any kind of movement" in time.

There is only the present, and things move in the present.

In the present, we can store things in memory, we can access our memories, we can make an estimate about "the future".

There is no past or future in reality.

Yes we can access our memories, and if we spend 2 weeks in a box with nothing to do we may keep thinking "I'm so bored, I wanna get out" and we may store many bad memories, I'm still thinking about wanting to get out, now it's getting darker and I still want to get out, it's been 2 days and I still want to get out, and so on.

Then, we have many memories about that 2 weeks, so we may say "it was very slow time". This is inaccurate. Even if there was time, it would move constantly. But there is no time at all, and all we have are the present memories. It is more accurate to saying something like "I have many memories of that one time in the box for 2 weeks, I remember on the 4th day when I kept thinking that it had already been 4 days, etc".

So maybe there is some kind of quale (the gayest word I've ever heard, by the way), but it is not about "perception of time", only about memories of passed events.

Comment: Gravity is "just" spacetime curvature, that doesn't mean it doesn't exist. Similarly, I think it's not true we don't experience time in the present.  I ask you to wait for as long as you percieved a football match, I can even compare your subjective changes in this quale (so it's not just a mathematical function of our brain that gets biased sometimes)

Comment: At the same time, it changes dramatically. I gave one example of that in the question. Another is Vsauce's experiment. https://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=%23&ved=0ahUKEwjx3bmn2vrYAhUEI1AKHTvAAc0QwqsBCCcwAA&usg=AOvVaw0VTJzWxrN8ZFOD4xbU2nov

Comment: Gravity is real, but time is not. And how do you compare the changes? You can only observe how things are and how they move in the present.

Comment: just like they compare sweetness of different substances: you give your respondents a solution of sugar and a solution of stevia and ask them which of them they percieved as sweeter

Comment: So you give them sugar in the present and ask them to tell you about their current memories and observe their response in the present. None of this suggests that time exists

Comment: No it doesn't. But since you wrote *how do you compare the changes?*, I gave an example of another quale that can be compared even though you don't experience the compared perceptions at the same time ("in the present"). The reason is that for us humans, the past felt equally vivid as the present. You might argue that we just *think* they were equally vivid but the thing is, as a rationalist I believe it's more philosophically sustainable rather to think that we just "forget" the vividness of the present once it becomes past.

Comment: But it's not important wheter or not time exists, just like it's not important wheter or not consciousness is real when we're discussing the sharability of qualia. The important thing is that the information we share can bear the full experience of the quale. In my answer, I argued we can't because time perception consists of all the other perceptions. So I think it indeed is special (since it's a mix of other qualia) but not in its sharability. What we share when we guess time is just the biological outcome that can be shared just like colorblindness.

Comment: But the sheer fact that we can't describe this biological outcome I think means that time *perception* is real which is important for now. You might say *i think, therefore i am* means time's not real but 1. it doesn't mean that other things don't exist 2. it's an axiom, it's not the absolute truth 3. Would you argue space is not real as well? You can say it's just the experience of space that there is, but what's the difference? Isn't it in the line of thinking of *cogito ergo sum* the definition of realness?